# Unity - Sprite with collider2d hits a rigidbody - Searching for a way to make the rigidbody not to react

Tags: c#, unity

When a sprite with a box collider 2d hits the game object (rigid body),

the collision detection is fired and I get the event.

However, the sprite moves the rigidbody and I have trouble restoring it back.

I tried to create a collision detection without ridigbody but without success.

Is there a way so that the ridigbody is never moved?

Hint: I can't make it static, since the rigidbody becomes immovable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the GameObjects, you could mark the `Is Trigger` box in the inspector, or from a script, do: `collider.isTrigger = true`. This will yield events in a similar way, but use the `OnTrigger` methods instead of the `OnCollision` methods, as described [here](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/colliders-as-triggers).

Comment: using isTrigger means actually that onTrigger not onCollision events will be called?

Comment: @mirzahat Correct. You can still handle events in a similar way. One distinction to note though, is `OnTriggerEnter2D` will have an object of type `Collider2D` as an argument, as opposed to `OnCollisionEnter2D`, which would get passed a `Collision2D`.